# Errno is not set using c++ system api while invoking powershell script

Tags: c++, windows, powershell, system-calls

I am using **system** api to invoke the powershell script and that script is not setting the errno to any value which is not giving me hint if the command execution is success or failure.

Below is my powersehll script which is simply setting the exit code, but this exit code is not set when I am calling this script using c++ system api.

**test.ps1**

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function ExitWithCode {
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  param($exitcode)
  $host.SetShouldExit($exitcode);
  exit
}
ExitWithCode -exitcode 1
```

**Execution of script using c++ program**

```
        string cmd = "";
        std::getline(cin, cmd);
        errno = 0;
        cout <<" system " <<cmd << "  ------> " << endl;
        cout << system(cmd.c_str()) << " errno " << errno << endl;
```

**Output of the c++ program**

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File "C:\test.ps1"
system   powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File "C:\test.ps1"  ------>
0 errno 0
```

system command output is 0 but the errno is alos set to 0. Any idea why the errno is not set?

Comment: A return code of zero from a program or a script is usually an indicator that it succeeded. A small positive number is an indication of failure. Besides, it doesn't matter what happens in the program or the script, the value of `errno` *migh* be set only if the [`std::system`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system) function itself fails. It's not an indicator that there was an error in the program or script you execute.

Comment: Other than that, unless a function is documented to set the value of `errno` when it succeeds, you should only ever check `errno` after a function have failed (and also documented as setting `errno`). If a function doesn't fail then the value of `errno` is actually *indeterminate* and should not be checked.

Comment: Is `std::system()` even supposed to set `errno`?

Comment: @Galik It doesn't seem to be documented as doing it. Though depending on the operating system used the functions `std::system` uses might set it. But now on Windows, rather then `GetLastError` needs to be checked. But again, only if the `std::system` function itself fails.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I checked GetLastError also it was set to zero. Is there any other way to know if the execution of the caller porgram is success or not, perhaps using _exec or _execp?

Comment: You need to read [the Windows documentation for `system`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/system-wsystem?view=msvc-160).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`exit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_language_keywords#exit) keyword in PowerShell sets the return code to `0` by default. As you are just calling `exit` without an argument, the return code will always be `0`. Change your function to this:

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function ExitWithCode {
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  param($exitcode)
  exit $exitcode
}
ExitWithCode -exitcode 1
```

Or don't reinvent the wheel and just call:

```
exit 1
```